# Showing the date of the latest edit, instead of node's posting date

Tags: 7, datetime, nodes

I have some nodes I update frequently, but in content pane I can see the posting date of node.

How can I make Drupal 7 show the date of the latest edit, instead of the posting date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hook_node_view to add the change date content like this:

```
/**
* Implement hook_node_view()
*/
function youmodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

    $changde_date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $node->changed);
    $node->content['body'][0]['#markup'] = "<div class='changed-date'>$changde_date</div>" . $node->content['body'][0]['#markup'];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would tackle this in a [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), either in a module or in your theme.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node (&$variables)
{
   $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->changed);
}
```

Depending on your node template, you may also want to do something like

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node (&$variables)
{
   $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->changed);

   if (variable_get('node_submitted_' . $variables['node']->type, TRUE)) {
     $variables['display_submitted'] = TRUE;
     $variables['submitted'] = t('Edited by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
     $variables['user_picture'] = theme_get_setting('toggle_node_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $node)) : '';
   } else {
     $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
     $variables['submitted'] = '';
     $variables['user_picture'] = '';
   }    
}
```

so that your new `$date` gets used in `$submitted`, due to the [preproccess/process order](http://drupal.org/node/223430).

You can also play around with variants.  For example, you could have both created and last edited dates; you would juust need to set up the variables in the preprocess function, and then use them in your `node.tpl.php`.

Comment: What file in my themes folder would I be looking for to place the code into? Also, when updating node.tpl.php, all that you would have to do is call `print $var;` where you want it placed correct?

Comment: You would do this in template.php.  Change mytheme to the name of your theme, and clear all caches.  And yes, you would use print to output the variable.  The template file will have lots of examples.