# Show an "updated" timestamp on nodes

Tags: 7, datetime

Is there a way to show a "Last Updated" timestamp for nodes? Maybe even in views as well?

EDIT: Via a module or core configuration

Comment: This is near duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18852/showing-latest-edit-date-of-node-instead-of-nodes-post-date

Comment: Created an edit. Don't wish to re-write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN views, just include a `NODE/node last updated date` field in your row.  For nodes, take the advice of MPD and those commenting in [Showing the date of the latest edit, instead of node's posting date](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18852/showing-latest-edit-date-of-node-instead-of-nodes-post-date) about creating the *very* simple preprocess() and/or view() hooks.

Comment: Is there a way to show one updated date in views, like at the top or bottom of the view that shows the last time any content in that view was updated as opposed to having it show up in every row for every content in that view? I'm sure the answer is no =(

Comment: Nope.  Answer is yes.  You can use the header or footer sections of the view to do that along with replacement patterns.  Just use the date field and you can put it in either place.  Then either use CSS to not display the field in the rows, or have views load them and not display them.

Comment: Tricky, however, this works by showing the updated date of the first row content, as opposed to the last content that was edited within the view.

Comment: then sort the view by date :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed this same feature myself on two separate sites, so I wrote a little module you can try: https://www.drupal.org/project/updated